# How to get a random letter in VB6?

Tags: string, random, vb6, letters, alphabet

I cannot convert those I see in VB.Net
I wanted to create something like a "Word Factory"
So I need to produce a random letter.
I managed to get a random number using this

```
Dim x, first, last
first = 65
last = 90
x = Int((last - Min + 1) * Rnd + Min)
```

How about random letters from the alphabet? in VB6. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn an integer code point into a character with the `Chr()` function, and go back the other way with `Asc()`.

That means you can get a random letter with code such as:

```
Dim mych As String
mych = Chr(Asc("A") + 26 * Rnd)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now we are able to play a Word Factory game at my office using excel lol :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a similar technique to the random number, but have the random number as the index of an array of characters?

On unrelated note you may want to pay attention to the distribution of the random letters, weighting some of the more common letters so they occur more frequently.